# AWS Chime SDK | support to schedule moderated meetings

Tags: aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

Amazon Chime App supports [Scheduling moderated meeting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/ug/moderate-meeting.html)

Is it possible to schedule meeting with [amazon chime SDK](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js)?

tried to find out possible solutions but didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, have you got any solution regarding this?

Comment: Hi, have you got any answers for this?